# R CMD batch from cron (Mac) gives different results from source()

Tags: r, utf-8, cmd, cron, batch-processing

I am running a `R CMD batch` (that unfortunately I can't reproduce here) with `cron` (Mac).

But when it runs the script, the results are different from what I obtain sourcing directly from R ou RStudio.

The differences are mainly with commands involving strings, like `sapply(object, gsub, pattern="[[:alpha:]]|[[:punct:]]|\\s",replacement="")`.

Sourcing everything runs ok. With cron, `gsub` fails to substitute characters like `é á ã` etc.

I think maybe this has something to do with language options, though I am not sure how to address this problem.

How can I assure both `source` and `cron`'s `R CMD batch` get the same results?

Comment: I still did not figure out what is going on. Nobody? Even a small hint about where to begin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check your locale settings. Under locales I notice that the documentation says for OS/X that "Users of R in a terminal may need to set the locale to something like ‘en_GB.UTF-8’ if it defaults to ‘C’ (as it sometimes does when logging it remotely and in batch jobs: note whether Terminal sets the LANG environment variable is an (advanced) option, but the default)."

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. But do you know how to know what settings `cron` is using?

Comment: In the Terminal, type 'locale'. Whatever it shows for LANG=, etc. is what your system uses (cron, bash and pretty much everything character-wise) unless you've edited /etc/profile to set it to something else. It's probably "en_US.UTF-8". As an alternative to R CMD you can also use Rscript which is the built-in for running R scripts from the command line.

Comment: I have figured out how to solve it. You have to assure that `cron` has the same environment varibles that shell has, you have to define them before the `cron`job, it is working now! (but I did have some trouble to get ir right!)